# CSS position absolute tag is disabling my attribute tags

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I am trying to position my navbar and the moment I use `absolute` in `CDS_MiniNav`, it places my bar in the correct area and then disables all of the links -.- I am so irritated.

:CSS

```
.CDS_MiniNAV{
     position: absolute !important;
     top: 18%;
     right: 0%;
 }
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="row col-md-6 pull-right CDS_MiniNAV">
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="INT_CertificationsXREF" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand dash CDS_Margin"><font size="2">My Certifications &nbsp; |</font></a>

        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Managerial" asp-action="Approval" class="navbar-brand dash CDS_Margin"><font size="2">Approve Certifications &nbsp; |</font></a>

        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Managerial" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand dash CDS_Margin">  <font size="2">Search Certifications &nbsp; |</font></a>

        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Managerial" asp-action="Options" class="navbar-brand dash CDS_Margin"><font size="2">Options</font></a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean they don't have highlights anymore and the cursor is an I?

Comment: yessssssssssssss

Comment: That's *probably* because they don't have the `href` attribute.

Comment: This in asp.net-core so you must use the a tag when making links to other views. href is not allowed for this type of coding.

Comment: asp.net-core should be generating `href`'s at runtime from the `asp-*` attributes.

Comment: Note that the **font** tag does not exist, it has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Andy G would that cause it to do that? When I take off CDS_MiniNav it works just fine

Comment: No idea, I never use it, because it is obsolete.